# Half and half bread, too salty and no salt?

Tags: bread

In putting the ingredients into my bread machine the top came off of the salt. I scooped out as much as could but it still has too much salt. I started another batch with no salt.

Do I thoroughly mix them together or make a half salty and half sweet loaf?

Comment: @Jolenealaska and that was after I read it for typos!

Comment: Happens to the best us! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thoroughly mix them! If you mix them, you may end up with a completely palatable (even tasty) loaf; if you have half salt and half no salt, you'll likely end up with *two* unapalatable loaves.

Comment: Split both in half and tried both. Completely mixed was the best result.